# LOAD DATA INFILE usage to import CSV?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, load-data-infile

The general LOAD DATA INFILE syntax to work on a local machine is:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] LOCAL INFILE 'file_name'
[REPLACE | IGNORE]
INTO TABLE tbl_name
[CHARACTER SET charset_name]
[{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
    [ESCAPED BY 'char']
]
[LINES
    [STARTING BY 'string']
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
]
[IGNORE number LINES]
```

I am writing a program in Ruby which is supposed to be able to import all kinds of CSV into a MySQL table.

The CSV file is stored perfectly in a variable and headers are fetched and the table is created perfectly. The issue is each CSV file I get is different and the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` parameter has to be modified in order to identify the CSV file formatting.

For example in one CSV, the `LINES TERMINATED BY` option has to be set to `'\n'` and in another it has to be set to `'\r'`. Similarly, in one CSV `ESCAPED BY '[char]'` has to be present to be imported correctly and in another it must not be present.

Is there any possible way to provide multiple values to check? Like `TERMINATED BY '\n or \r'` or `ENCLOSED BY '\ or "'`?

**`EDIT:`**

When I do:

```
FasterCSV.foreach(csv) do |row|
  @first = row
  break
end
```

I get the first row. Is it possible to detect the line terminator, whether its `\n` or `\r\n` or `\r` from that single row?

Comment: i have worked this load file option but according to my knowledge you need to check the the option and provide it manually and run the load file script accordingly.

Comment: I am using this gem called `FasterCSV` to read the csv file...any idea if it can be used to detect the CSV formatting and return that to the query?

Comment: i have no idea about it.

Comment: The DBM is capable of loading CSV faster. `terminated by`, `enclosed by` and `escaped by` let you define a CSV or TSV record, and you're going to have to set those whether you do it in Ruby, or SQL. The [built-in CSV class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html), under the covers is FasterCSV. Also, don't plead for help. Good questions showing effort get rewarded by upvotes, and by people offering answers not because of pleading or because they're new. Show that you've put effort by displaying some code you wrote to solve this.

Comment: Even if I use the inbuilt CSV(which is very similar to FasterCSV), i would need to execute the Load Infile in order to import the contents of the file which is where the fix is, since I know not the parameters to provide for `terminated by`, `escaped by` and `enclosed by`. Am using ruby because, am working on a rails application where this is being invoked. And about the please part, you're right :)

Comment: It *is* FasterCSV, it's not similar to it. Ruby + CSV + the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) gem is a good combination to do this if you want to avoid writing SQL at all. You can read one line from your file into memory, instead of the whole file which isn't scalable, and use that to determine your line-endings, field separator, and possibly quoting, but CSV won't do it for you, you'll have to do that yourself. Look into the OS's `file` command to help you figure out your file's formatting.

Comment: I know that man..which is exactly why am asking if there's any other methods than the usual ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, so I ended up writing a mini-parser for a few "testLines" before I load each file.

```
public static void findTerminator(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedReader lines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int countLines = 0;
    int testLines = 15;
    int c;
    int[] terminators = { 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0D0A }; //\n, \r, \r\n
    int[] counters = { 0, 0, 0 };
    try {
        while (((c = lines.read()) != -1) && (countLines <= testLines)) {
            for (int d = 0; d < terminators.length; d++) {
                if (c == terminators[d]) { 
                    counters[d]++; 
                    countLines++;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    int max = 0;
    int maxindex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
        if (max < counters[i]) { 
            max = counters[i]; 
            maxindex = i; 
        }
    }
    terminator = (char)terminators[maxindex];
    System.out.println("Terminator: '" + terminators[maxindex] + "'");
}
```